# How to read and process a file in Python that is too big for memory?

Tags: python

I have csv file that looks like:

```
1,2,0.2
1,3,0.4
2,1,0.5
2,3,0.8
3,1,0.1
3,2,0.6
```

First column correspond to `user_a`, second to `user_b` and third correspond to `score`. I want to find for every `user_a`, a `user_b` value that maximizes the `score`. For this example output should look like (output in form of dictionary preferable but not requred):

```
1 3 0.4
2 3 0.8
3 2 0.6
```

The problem is that file is very big (millions of rows) and I try to find way to do it without out of memory error. Because of environment setup I cannot use **Pandas**, Dask and other packages with dataframes.

I used the yield function to keep the memory needed for computation, but I still get an out-of-memory error. Any advice on how to reduce memory consumption would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this that would cause a memory leak; perhaps your file just has too many distinct values for `User_A`, so you can't fit them all in memory at once. You could add a counter to check how many lines it's able to process before it runs out of memory, or try stepping through the code to see if `result` contains anything it shouldn't. By the way, `yield` is doing nothing here to save memory; it is `for line in open(...):` which ensures the whole file is not loaded in memory at once.

Comment: As an aside, why are you using `while True` with a `next` call wrapped in `try ... except: StopIteration`??? Just use `for a,b, s in read_large_data(file_name, sep): ...`

Comment: Based upon the sample data it appears that the data is duplicated: `1,2,0.5` is the same information as `2,1,0.5`. You can half the volume of memory required by sorting the values for `user_a` and `user_b` and using this information as the key to store the `score` value.

Comment: @DanNagle Good eye; can OP clarify whether this symmetry is guaranteed for the whole file? That said, even for a symmetric relation it is not necessarily the case that if A maximises B's score, that B also maximises A's score - consider e.g. `(A,B,1), (B,A,1), (A,C,2), (C,A,2)`.

Comment: How many million rows, how many different user_a, and how much memory do you have? Your example shows all ordered pairs for users 1 to 3. Is your real data likewise all ordered pairs for users 1 to n? And is your real data sorted as your example data is? A realistic data generator code would be good for understanding the situation and for testing.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, symmetry is guaranteed for the whole file

Comment: @KellyBundy 50 million rows, 1 million different user_a, and I have 32GB of memory. Yes, correct, the real data is ordered pairs and sorted

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A million different users should take maybe 200 MB, not exceed 32 GB. Something isn't right.

Comment: @KellyBundy In a real table, each score is represented not as a number but as a multidimensional matrix, and I need to do additional computation with this score and I have to compare value of this score with each previous scores before I can add it to the final result.

Comment: @Mario The question says *"I cannot use Pandas"*.

Comment: Then it would be helpful to show such matrices and what you do with them. I mean, it now sounds like your desired *result* is too big for your memory. There might be a way to use less memory for the same result, but we'd need to know more details. And please put the additional information into the question, not just into comments.

Comment: Does this _"and I have to compare value of this score with each previous scores before I can add it to the final result"_ mean that to find the "maximum" you can't just compare the last maximum candidate with the newest item, but you need the whole history?

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you are saying *"Yes, correct, the real data is ordered pairs and sorted"*. So why can't you just do the following:

```py
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def max_key(row): return float(row[2])

def find_max_score(file_name, sep=","):
    result = {"User_A": [], "User_B": [], "Score": []}
    with open(file_name, "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=sep)
        for user_a, rows in groupby(reader, key=itemgetter(0)):
            _, user_b, score = max(rows, key=max_key)
            result["User_A"].append(user_a)
            result["User_B"].append(user_b)
            result["Score"].append(score)
    return result
```

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh, seems I've missed something?

Comment: @KellyBundy Do you mean the sorting includes the score: Then it would indeed be even easier (just grabbing the last row in group)?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, I too don't see memory as a limiting factor here. I don't quite understand the code in the question, in the `while` loop there's a `result.index` involved and dictionaries don't have that. So I thought the actual program has a memory-consuming feature that isn't necessary.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, just saw it too (at first I thought it was a relict from a Pandas version).

Comment: Ok they clarified what wasn't right - the "scores" are in fact larger. And I guess they keep the whole max-score matrix for each user, so it's really their desired *result* that's too big for their memory, and then there might just be *no* way to do it... (other than getting more (virtual) memory).

Answer (score 1):

Give [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) a try (*I must confess - I'm the author*)

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

# creates an iterable of rows as dicts
# consider wrapping with tqdm to see the progress
rows = (
    Table.from_csv("input.csv", header=["user_a", "user_b", "score"])
    .update(score=c.col("score").as_type(float))
    .into_iter_rows(dict)
)

# gen_converter writes & compiles ad-hoc python function
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item("user_a"))
    .aggregate(
        {
            "user_a": c.item("user_a"),
            "user_b": c.ReduceFuncs.MaxRow(c.item("score")).item("user_b"),
            "score": c.ReduceFuncs.MaxRow(c.item("score")).item("score"),
        }
    )
    .gen_converter()
)
Table.from_rows(converter(rows)).into_csv("output.csv", include_header=False)
```

On my M1 mac - python 3.9: with `tqdm` and `itertools.cycle` overhead it operates at: 5894860 rows/s. The result is:

```
1,3,0.4
2,3,0.8
3,2,0.6
```

**However, since the dictionary output is preferable** (let's also work with tuples, not dicts, just as an example):

```py
rows = (
    Table.from_csv("input.csv", header=["user_a", "user_b", "score"])
    .update(score=c.col("score").as_type(float))
    .into_iter_rows(tuple)
)
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item(0))
    .aggregate(
        (
            c.item(0),
            {
                "user_b": c.ReduceFuncs.MaxRow(c.item(2)).item(1),
                "score": c.ReduceFuncs.MaxRow(c.item(2)).item(2),
            },
        )
    )
    .as_type(dict)
    .gen_converter()
)
result = converter(rows)
```

This operates at 6050825 rows/s and the result is:

```
In [32]: result
Out[32]:
{'1': {'user_b': '3', 'score': 0.4},
 '2': {'user_b': '3', 'score': 0.8},
 '3': {'user_b': '2', 'score': 0.6}}
```

**If you still run out of memory -- GNU to the rescue**:

*The below assumes there are no commas in columns.*

- `sort`: numeric reverse sort by 1st and 3rd columns with `,` as a separator
- `awk`: take unique ones by first column

`sort -t ',' -k 1,3 -n -r input.csv | awk -F ',' -vOFS=, '!($1 in seen) {print $0; seen[$1]}'`

```
3,2,0.6
2,3,0.8
1,3,0.4
```

Comment: Can these (particularly that GNU oneliner) handle their multidimensional matrices?

Comment: These are just utils to process streams of data / text files. So I don't think it will be efficient if you reshape your n-dims to 2-dims, as it will have to split and read all values of the first row to get to the second one.

Comment: Look for out-of-core tools/algorithms if data doesn't fit into memory.